# ¿Cómo soluciono el mensaje de error "would clobber existing tag" al hacer "git pull"?

Tags: git, git-tag, git-pull

En mi entorno de trabajo tenemos la etiqueta "production" para marcar siempre la última versión que está en producción. La creamos a mano al hacer una *release* y, por tanto, va cambiando periódicamente.

Lo que ocurre después es que cuando hago un `git pull` en local mi etiqueta "production" no apunta al mismo sitio que la que hay en remoto, por lo que me sale el mensaje de error:

```
! [rejected]          production -> production  (would clobber existing tag)
```

Es decir, git me avisa de que rechaza esto porque *machacaría la etiqueta ya existente*.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el `git pull` funcione correctamente sin recibir este mensaje de error? [Leí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58438257/1983854) que se puede hacer `git fetch --tags -f`, lo que fuerza el "pull" de las etiquetas, sobreescribiendo las que estén en local. ¿Pero puede hacerse todo en un único comando?

Comment: No lo pongo como respueta porque no he podido probarlo, pero `git pull --prune-tags` creo que podría hacer lo que estás buscando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que tener en cuenta  lo que dice la documentación sobre `git pull`

> git-pull - Fetch from and integrate with another repository or a local
> branch
> ...
> Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch. In its > default mode, git pull is shorthand for git fetch followed by git merge FETCH_HEAD

Con lo cual te está diciendo que `git pull` es lo mismo que `git fetch`

Y con ello podemos entender que `git pull --tags -f` te forzará bajar los tags de la misma forma que lo harías con `git fetch --tags -f`

> -f, --force
> When git fetch is used with : refspec it may refuse to update the local branch as discussed in the  part of the git-fetch(1) documentation. This option overrides that check.

También relevante:

> Until Git version 2.20, and unlike when pushing with git-push(1), any updates to refs/tags/* would be accepted without + in
> the refspec (or --force). When fetching, we promiscuously considered
> all tag updates from a remote to be
> forced fetches. Since Git version 2.20, fetching to update refs/tags/* works the same way as when pushing. I.e. any updates will
> be rejected without + in the refspec (or --force).

Comment: no está diciendo que sean lo mismo, git pull hace más cosas (`git merge FETCH_HEAD`)

Comment: Si claro, si no no existiría git pull. lo que quiero decir es que le puedes pasar los mismos parámetros que a git fetch.

Git pull también se comporta como un git rebase según los parámetros que le pases etc.. por lo que no es 1-1 en cuanto al comando, pero para tu ejemplo, que tienes un git fetch y no sabes como hacerlo con un git pull es básicamente los mismos flags porque son comandos similares